# how to use Loops for inserting records in sql table using vb 2015?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using the below code of vb 2015 to insert records into sql server table from xml file.
The problem is that a new records are actually inserted but with "Null" values except this column "DBDumpVersion" as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

```vb
Dim sqlPrGroupComm As New SqlCommand
Dim PrGroupNodeList As XmlNodeList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//PrGroup")
Dim PrGroupChildNodeList As XmlNodeList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//PrGroup/Key")
For Each PrGroupNodes As XmlNode In PrGroupNodeList
    For Each PrGroupNodesATTVAL As XmlAttribute In PrGroupNodes.Attributes
        sqlinstPrGroupStr = "INSERT INTO PrGroup (" & PrGroupNodesATTVAL.Name & ")"

        sqlinstPrGroupStr += " VALUES " & "('" & PrGroupNodesATTVAL.Value & "')"

        sqlPrGroupComm.CommandText = sqlinstPrGroupStr
    Next

    sqlPrGroupComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

Next
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are using

Comment: Why use loops at all? check out these [examples of bulk insert from xml on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx)

Comment: What does the xml document look like? What does your table design look like?

Comment: This table consists of two xml nods that's why i can't bulk copy or import the records.

Comment: You really should parameterize your queries to prevent sql injection.

Comment: The last two columns (Id, OrderNo) from  another node.

Comment: Have you looked at the value of `sqlinstPrGroupStr` to check it is what you want it to be?

Comment: Yes i've used a listbox to check it's value and it was giving the correct value for each attribute also i've used data table with gridview and also worked find !!! But for sql table it keep giving "Null" !!!

Comment: @A..R.Azzeh I suspect you checked it inside the loop, but it is only *used* after the loop which means it has been constructed for only the last XmlAttribute.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes i've checked values from inside the loop and when i moved listbox sources out of loop it gave same as table result only the last column with value. But i've tried BulkCopy and Table Adapter snd it worked fine, sql command only is not working and thats my problem !

Comment: @A..R.Azzeh That's why you aren't seeing the problem. For example. *when the query is executed* for the first row, the value of `sqlinstPrGroupStr` is `INSERT INTO PrGroup (DBDumpVersion) VALUES ('10')`. You need to think about how you are building the SQL statement.